# Create Custom Cross Validation in Spark ML

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to both Spark and PySpark Data Frames and ML. How can I create a custom cross validation for the ML library. I want for example change the way the training folds are formed, e.g. **stratified splits**.

This is my current code

```
numFolds = 10
predictions = []

lr = LogisticRegression()\
     .setFeaturesCol("features")\
     .setLabelCol('label')

# Grid search on LR model
lrparamGrid = ParamGridBuilder()\
     .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0])\
     .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0])\
     .addGrid(lr.maxIter, [5, 10, 20])\
     .build()

pipelineModel = Pipeline(stages=[lr])
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()

cv = CrossValidator()\
     .setEstimator(pipelineModel)\
     .setEvaluator(evaluator)\
     .setEstimatorParamMaps(lrparamGrid).setNumFolds(5)

# My own Cross-Validation with stratified splits
for i in range(numFolds):
     # Use Stratified indexOfStratifiedSplits
     trainingData = df[df.ID.isin(indexOfStratifiedSplits[i][0])]
     testingData = df[df.ID.isin(indexOfStratifiedSplits[i][1])]

# Training and Grid Search
cvModel = cv.fit(trainingData)
predictions.append(cvModel.transform(testingData))
```

I would like to have a Cross-Validation class to be called like this

```
cv = MyCrossValidator()\
     .setEstimator(pipelineModel)\
     .setEvaluator(evaluator)\
     .setEstimatorParamMaps(lrparamGrid).setNumFolds(5)\
     # Option 1
     .setSplitIndexes(indexOfStratifiedSplits)
     # Option 2
     .setSplitType("Stratified",ColumnName)
```

I don't know whether the best option is to create a class that extends [CrossValidation.fit](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tuning/CrossValidator.scala#L74) or [Passing Functions to Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#passing-functions-to-spark). Either option is challenging for me as newbie, I tried copying GitHub codes but I get tons of errors, specially I don't speak Scala, but this pipeline is faster in Scala API.

Although I have my own functions to split the data in the way I want (sklearn based), I want to use Pipelines, grid search and cv together, such that all permutations are distributed rather than executed in master. That loop with "My own Cross-Validation" only uses part of the cluster nodes as the loop happens in master/driver.

Any Python or Scala API is fine, but preferable Scala.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Python, Sklearn provides you the `sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold` function. You can use [Sparkit-learn](https://github.com/lensacom/sparkit-learn)  who aims to provide scikit-learn functionality and API on PySpark.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [spark-stratifier](https://github.com/interviewstreet/spark-stratifier) if you want a Stratified CrossValidator for PySpark.